# How deserialize raw types?

Tags: json.net

I have the following code:

```
var str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>("dGVzdA==");
```

But it doesn't work, exception says: "Unexpected character encounterecd while parsing value: d. Path '', line 0 position 0.
It's clearly trying to read this as a json although it's supposed to read it into a byte[]

Comment: Well it is called JSONConvert so I guess it expects a JSON Object

Comment: but it works for things like int

Comment: ok apparently the base64 string needs to be wrapped in "" for this to work as expected. weird

Answer (score 1):

[`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) expects a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) expression.  `dGVzdA==` is not valid JSON, therefore you get an error.  In JSON, all strings must be quoted, per the spec. If you add quotes to your base-64 string, that makes it a valid JSON string value, so then the deserializer can handle it.  Here is a short fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BuQc1R

Comment: I dont know the type that I'm trying to convert, it could be a primitive type or anything else. The weird thing about Newtonsoft is that it apparently requires the base64 string to be wrapped in quotes when deserializing but throws an error when you have those quotes when serializing it.